# Radio button stays selected even after page refresh in IE11

Tags: html, internet-explorer-11

I have a page, where for filtering a list we have used few radio buttons.

- ALL (default selected using checked='checked')
- MATCHED
- REST

```html
<input type="radio" value="ALL" name="options" class="radioStyle" checked autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" value="MATCHED" name="options" class="radioStyle" autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" value="REST" name="options"  class="radioStyle" autocomplete="off">
```

The problem is that, once user selects any of the radio button and then refresh the page in IE 11, those radio buttons are still selected, but the result are listed from default radio button i.e "ALL".

This behaviour is not seen in Chrome or Firefox, it seems to be there in IE11 only.

Even i tried adding autocomplete='off', but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `checked="checked"` ? I know IE9 had a similar problem and this method was used to correct it.

```
<input type="radio" value="ALL" name="options" checked="checked" class="radioStyle" autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" value="MATCHED" name="options" class="radioStyle" autocomplete="off">
<input type="radio" value="REST" name="options"  class="radioStyle" autocomplete="off">
```

If that doesn't work for you, how about using a cookie session to clear it out?

Comment: Using "checked" or "checked='checked'", both are same. Mine is HTML valid and yours is XHTML. I don't think any diff is there. Both finally turns to Boolean property. Anyway this also does not seem to work.